# Window for taking getch input not showing using ncursesw but works with ncurses

Tags: c++, unicode, ncurses, getch, widechar

I need to use -lncursesw to print out unicode characters otherwise it wouldn't work however after compiling it with this, the window for user input shows up but when I type characters to it, it doesn't show but still able to type. I honestly don't know how to make this work, I have set the locale with setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

this is the code for input:

`while ((ch = getch()) != KEY_F(9))
        driver(ch);`

and an example piece of code for handling the input (using switch cases) this is the default:

```
    default:
        form_driver(commandForm, ch);
        showGrid();
        wrefresh(mainScreen);
        break;
```

This is what it looks like, the first picture using -lncursesw and second using -lncurses.

[image: This is using -lncursesw]

[image: This is using -lncurses]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using -lform, use -lformw.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a function

```
form_driver(commandForm, ch);
```

which will not handle wide-characters.  Also, `getch` doesn't handle wide-characters (hint: try select/paste those double-line box characters shown in your screenshot into the input field).

If you intend handling Unicode (wide-characters), you should use [`get_wch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html). Also,
ncurses has an alternate function [`form_driver_w`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_driver.3x.html#h3-form_driver_w) (in the *ncursesw* library of course) which may help with your problem.

Comment: it is solved now. The problem was because we were using -lform -lncursesw instead of -lformw -lncursesw.